# Confused on hidding element

Tags: javascript, html

I have two button where green button on click so +1 on count and show not show the value until the red button is pressed but it is not happening but rather when I click the green button the value is stored, but is shown too and the value should only be showed when red button is pressed.

Any kind of hints or help will be a lot appreciated

```js
 var clicks = 0;
 function clickME() {
     clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  }
 function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
 document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
 }
```

```css
.grow:active
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
 }
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>



   <input type="image" class="grow" src="green.jpg" onClick="clickME()">
<img src="red.jpg" type="button" name="type"  onclick="setVisibility('sub3',    'inline');";>
  <br><br><br><div id="sub3"> <p id="clicks"></div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Your `<p id="clicks">` has not closing `</p>` tag

Comment: @caramba Thanks but the output is still the same.

Comment: Thank you So much Everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var clicks = 0;
 function clickME() {
     clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  }
 function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
 document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
 }
```

```css
.grow:active
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
 }

#sub3 {   /* this was the missing part */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="image" class="grow" src="green.jpg" onClick="clickME()">
<img src="red.jpg" type="button" name="type"  onclick="setVisibility('sub3',    'inline');";>
  <br><br><br><div id="sub3"> <p id="clicks"></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to first make that div hidden by `display:none`

```js
var clicks = 0;
 function clickME() {
     clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  }
 function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
   //alert(visibility);
 document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
 }
```

```css
.grow:active
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
 }

#sub3{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="image" class="grow" src="green.jpg" onClick="clickME()">
<img src="red.jpg" type="button" name="type"  onclick="setVisibility('sub3',    'block');";>
  <br><br><br><div id="sub3"> <p id="clicks"></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `setVisibility("sub3","none");` onload or set visibility to `none` in the html itself.

```js
 var clicks = 0;
setVisibility("sub3","none");
 function clickME() {
     clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  }
 function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
 document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
 }
```

```css
.grow:active
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
 }
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>



   <input type="image" class="grow" src="green.jpg" onClick="clickME()">
<img src="red.jpg" type="button" name="type"  onclick="setVisibility('sub3',    'inline');";>
  <br><br><br><div id="sub3"> <p id="clicks"></div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the initial visibility of `sub3` to none either using stylesheet

```
#sub3
{
display:none;
}
```

or inline `<div id="sub3" style="display:none"> <p id="clicks"></p></div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
.grow:active
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
 }</style>


<script>
 var clicks = 0;
 function clickME() {
     clicks += 1;


  }
 function setVisibility() {
 document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
 }
 </script>
 <input type="image" class="grow" src="green.jpg" onClick="clickME()">
<img src="red.jpg" type="button" name="type"  onclick="setVisibility()";>
  <br><br><br><div id="sub3"> <p id="clicks"></p></div>

</body>

</html>
```